# Twitter Bootstrap - Image classes not applying?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.2 and the latest version of Chrome. I was reading about [Images](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#images) and decided to try out the img-rounded, -circle and -polaroid classes on some test images to see what they would look like.

Problem is as you can see from [this example page](http://adambalan.com/WordPressDev/uncategorized/178) the images are not rounded, not a circle and poorly polaroided....

Any tips?

Comment: Your images are not squared, so you will not get circle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the effects are working as they should, it just looks like the images you're using have a thick white border on the sides, which might make it look like the effects aren't working. It's a little more obvious if you make the page background a different color than white using Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: Looks like you've changed the images on your example page, but the originals looked like they were being resized on the fly. In that case you'd have to check the resizing code or settings to see if it can crop the image instead of padding it, or use a size closer to the original image dimensions so the padding isn't as thick.